# Inductor size versus tolerance

Tags: circuit-design, inductor, tolerance

Say I’m planning to prototype some circuits (filters, oscillators, etc.) by soldering the component leads together in a “hairball” construction.  If I use typical 10% or 20% tolerance inductors, how small an inductor can I design with before worrying about the component lead inductances becoming a larger issue than the component tolerances?

Comment: This is difficult to answer given that we don't know what your construction is like. Why not just use large enough inductors to make it less dependent on parasitics?

Comment: The question is how large is your “large enough”?  And what isn’t?

Comment: That depends on how your system is physically constructed.

Comment: You should also worry about the inductor's self-resonant frequency if you plan on using it at high frequency. An inductor spec sheet might include a test frequency, and if you're really lucky, include SRF (self-resonant frequency).

Answer (score 1):

RF stuff at high frequency requires a certain amount of preplanning to take into account the parasitics of your substrate and interconnect.

Part of that is doing a trial layout (a ‘hairball’ counts as a layout), extracting parasitics, and doing a simulation. That sim also requires accurate models for your components.

The sim will also tell you not only whether your stuff works, but also your tolerance sensitivity, using a ‘monte carlo’ method to model tolerance. That’s ultimately how you decide what your tolerances need to be.

Your filter type has a major influence on this by the way. Topology, number of poles (order), type (Bessel, Chebyshev, elliptical) and so forth. This is actually more important than the parasitics. And the higher the frequency, the smaller the values, and, yes, the more influence the parasitics will have.

Answer (score 1):

For 'typical' wire diameters, reckon 1nH per mm for straight hookup wire, or component leads. So if you have an inductor with 10mm leads, that adds 20nH to its inductance, or 2% of 1uH. Of course, you have to add more for any loops that you enclose.